# In Dart how to get the ID of clicked SVG object?

Tags: dom, svg, mouseevent, dart

For the Dart code below:

```
for(var SVG_Element in SVG_Element_list){
  SVG_Element.onClick.listen((event){
  //some code
  });
}
```

How to determine the ID of the clicked object? I tried "event.target.id" and would only get the type of the Element like "line" or "circle".

How to get the ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to look at your markup to know precisely what is going on, but here is an example where `element.target.id` works with an SVG element.

Given the following markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="mySVGElement">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" stroke="black"
    stroke-width="20" fill="blue" id="myCircle" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

The following code gets you the id of the `<svg>`:

```
import 'dart:html';
void main() {
  query('#container').onClick.listen((event) {
    print(event.target.id);
  });
}
```

Is your use case different?  Post some real code and I bet someone can help you with your specific situation.

Comment: My apologize!!! There were some bugs in my code!!! You are right and element.target.id works indeed!!!!